# Immutable Queries

Tags: hashmap, immutability

Please let me know is overriding equals and hashcode methods are mandatory even if key that I am using is immutable class.

For example I have an immutable class Employee and I want to use as key in a map. Do I need to override equals and hashcode methods.

```
public class Employee  {

    private int empId;
    private String name;

    public Employee(String name, int empId) {

       this.empId = empId;
       this.name=name;
    }

    public int getEmpId() {
       return empId;
    }
    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Kamal

Comment: Yes, you **do** need to override them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes, long answer: yeeeeees; especially since a `HashMap` and `HashSet` mandates that via the documentation. These are the main mechanics that are used internally inside a hash based structure.

Also you *should* implement the `Comparable` interface for you `Keys` (if you use `java-8`) - as that might be used internally to speed-up your search query.

The immutability is actually a very good thing for HashMap keys. Imagine that you put one key into the map (hashcode and equals is computed), then you alter it (changing it's hashcode/equals) and search for it again - it might not be found at all.

Comment: Thanks Eugene for your reply.